# How can I compile ARM inline assembly with Microsoft VC?

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, arm, inline-assembly

I have C code with arm inline assembly that uses the `asm ("...")` syntax. This code compiles fine with gcc.
However that syntax seems specific to gcc and this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/inline/writing-functions-with-inline-assembly?view=msvc-170) suggests that inline assembly is only supported for x86.
Isn't there a way to do inline assembly--I am not asking about writing entire functions in assembly--with the Microsoft VC compiler?

Comment: The link seems to answer your question pretty clearly: you can't, and there isn't.  So you'll have to rewrite.

Comment: Or use a different (\*cough\* better) compiler.  Of course, if the source really does use `asm("...")` GNU C Basic Asm, not `asm("..." : outputs : inputs : clobbers);`, then you should rewrite it even if using GCC or clang or other compilers supporting GNU extensions (https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/ConvertBasicAsmToExtended). Unless it's at global scope or inside an `__attribute__((naked))` function.  In which case you can easily transplant the asm to a separate `.S` or `.asm` file.

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't have the option of using another compiler here. Yes, using a separate assembly file is my current fallback but it forces me to use function calls and prevents inlining, which has an impact on performance.

Comment: So don't use inline asm at all.  Use intrinsics; MSVC has intrinsics for almost everything including privileged instructions; that's their better alternative to their inefficient `__asm{}` syntax they support on 32-bit x86, and the only option everywhere else.  Like I said, GNU C Basic asm (without operand constraints) also isn't usually usable inside functions; perhaps you meant `asm("..." : "=r"(var) : "r" (var2))` as your example, or perhaps `asm("..." ::: "memory")` for instructions that affect the machine state instead of doing computation.

Comment: The short answer is no, MSVC doesn't support inline asm except for 32-bit x86, and there it only supports its bad inefficient `__asm{}` syntax that can only take inputs and outputs via memory, not registers.  (Or an output by leaving a return value in EAX and falling off the end of a non-`void` function; it supports that hack even when inlining.)  Your only option for using the existing GNU C inline asm statements is to use a compiler that supports them, such as GCC or Clang.  You can use clang from inside visual studio, I think I've read.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks, I will look more closely at intrinsics. Do you think they allow to access specific hardware registers like cntvct_el0 and ugp? That's mostly what I was using inline asm for. And yes, I did mean `asm("..." : "=r"(var) : "r" (var2))` for the asm syntax.

Comment: Probably.  The Windows kernel itself is written in Visual C++ with intrinsics instead of inline asm, so you can do most things you'd ever want to do.  A header file might define constants for register numbers for special registers for use with intrinsics to read/write them.